# Escape option is not working while writing dataframe

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

While writing dataframe using "com.databricks.spark.csv" format, escape option is not working it taking default escape character as quotes(").

By following [this](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/390) , I have also tried keeping field quoted which contains quote(") but still, it is not working.

Following is my input data file(test.txt):

```
first , line
second " line
"third line"
fourth \n line
fifth \r line
sixth \ line
"seventh " line"
```

Here is my piece of code:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("D:\\Users\\vipareek\\AdHoc\\test.txt")
val schema = new StructType()
      .add("col1", StringType)
val schemaRDD = rdd.map(x => Row(x.toString))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(schemaRDD, schema)
df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("quoteMode", "NON_NUMERIC")
      .option("escape", "\\")
      .save("D:\\Users\\vipareek\\Projects\\FCA\\Datastax\\AdHoc\\out")
```

Finally, here is the output:

```
"col1"
"first , line"
"second "" line"
"""third line"""
"fourth \n line"
"fifth \r line"
"sixth \ line"
"""seventh "" line"""
```

As per the [readme](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) of "com.databricks.spark.csv" In this output escape character should be \ (backward slash) not " (quote) (For the last line i.e. "seventh " line").

Spark version is **1.6.1**

Could anyone please suggest something, am I missing anything here or using incorrectly?

Comment: +1. would love to see a fix for this. 

luckily, im using AWS Glue and can leverage Glue's DynamicFrames. my process takes significantly longer, but it completes and honors the escape character parameter.